# window.open is directing to itself instead of other page

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am trying to open a HTML page from a function in JavaScript and I am using `window.open("path to my second HTML page","_self")` but it is directing to the same HTML page. When I give the path as any web page on the internet say "https://www.google.com" it works properly! Why is this happening? Am I not giving the path correctly?

window.open('file:///home/akshata/Desktop/prj4/a.html','_self')

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your html file by specifying relative path in `window.open` use absolute path url instead.

And in the first line of your url add `http://`

Comment: The code works just fine when I manually open it with the browser. The link work fine too but when I run it by using index.js, instead of jumping to second page it remains on the same page and this is what I see in my address bar:  http://localhost:8000/  I think this is a port issue but I am not getting where I am going wrong!